# Adding a character at start, end, and between numbers

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
import os

class CsvToC:

This class takes creates a destination.h files from the source.csv binary
:param source_name: source_name is the name of the source.csv file.
:type source_name: str
:param destination_name: destination_name is the name of the destination.h file
:type destination_name: str
"""
def __init__(self,source_name,destination_name ):
    self.source_name = source_name
    self.destination_name = destination_name

@staticmethod
def __to_zero_one_function(number):
    """
    Helper function that transforms '000' to '0' and '255' to '1'
    """
    if number == "000" :
        return '0'
    elif number == "255":
        return '1'
      @staticmethod
   def __line_formatter(line):
    """
    Helper function to format line to be '0bxxxxxxxx, /n'
    """
    return str('0b' + line + ',\n' )

     def __extract_lines_from_csv(self) :
    """
        This function opens the csv files and returns a list of lines that are formated as 
           '0bxxxxxxxx, /n'
    """
    linesList = []
    with open(self.source_name, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        for row in reader:
            zero_one_rowList = map(self.__to_zero_one_function , row)
            zero_one_row = ''.join(zero_one_rowList)
            formated_line = self.__line_formatter(zero_one_row)
            linesList.append(formated_line)

    return linesList
    
    def __write_to_h(self ,linesList):
    """
    This func takes a linelist and writes it to a .h file
    """
    with open(self.destination_name , 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'const uint16_t totalLines ={len(linesList)};\n')
        f.write('const unsigned short bitsMatrix[totalLines] = {\n')
        f.write('// ' + str(self.source_name)  + '\n')
        f.writelines(linesList)
        f.write('};')
    return True

def convert_to_c(self):
    linesList = self.__extract_lines_from_csv()
    self.__write_to_h(linesList)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
   directory = str(input("Enter the directory Path : "))
   for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(directory):
     for file in files:
        if file.endswith((".csv")):
            file = CsvToC(str(file) , str(file)[:-3] + 'h')
            file.convert_to_c()
```

As it is, this code does what is supposed to do. However, I need to add more characters to the string in order to separate the start, end, and a character separation. Instead of `"0b00000000,"` I need `">0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0<"`. I tried to do it on my own but the results were not as expected:

> ```
> >0000*<,
> >0000*<,
> >0000*<,
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You wrote, "I tried to do it on my own". Did you mean that you rewrote the `__line_formatter` method? Can you show what you tried in the code? By the way, the code is very badly formatted (comments and indentation).

Comment: if number == "000" :
            return '0x'
        elif number == "255":
            return '1x'

Comment: return str('>' + line + 'x' '<,\n' )

Comment: I tried changing those two lines and still I don't get what I need, which is ">0x0x0x0x0x0x0<"

Comment: Hmmm, I think the core of your code (including what you tried to rewrite) is something like https://ideone.com/ipAxae. But I got `'>0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0xx<,'` (which is close to what you want, and easy to manipulate to get the demanded result), I can't reproduce `>0000*<,`...

Comment: first put code with correct indentations. And you could add example data directly in code - so we could simply copy and run it. We don't have csv files to test it.

Comment: `input()` always gives string so you don't need `str()` in `str(input())`. `os.walk()` always gives fienames as string so you don't need `str()`  in `str(file)`